# Multiple File Data Set Import Cleaning

Tags: batch, data-loader, bestpractice, largedatavolumes, file-processing

It is pre-Salesforce import, I have designed the Named Account structure inside Salesforce, and I have 1500 Hoover's D&B Family Trees with the same columns and headers in .xls form. What do I use to mass clean these files so we do not import bad data? Do I try a batch import of the folder via the dataloader but say in SF if  column equals  don't import so it errors via a VR? Do I clean in Access? How do I batch import? Do I use Excel? As of now I have too many rows, can I batch import only rows with XYZ? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I endedup using Power BI after mass merging the data with a script into a csv. I was able to filter out branches and records with incomplete data rather quickly.  Great tool for any admin to try.